# jquery is based on which javascript design pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Design Patterns used in the jQuery library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631039/design-patterns-used-in-the-jquery-library)

jquery is based on which javascript  design pattern ? And what design pattern to follow when writing jquery plugins ? Also what design pattern is generally used when writing OO javascript ?

Comment: I've added the "homework" tag. Please remove it if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @Shaz: Why should be homework?

Answer (score 2):

I think answer for your question is

[Design Patterns used in the jQuery library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3631039/568415)

Useful links for plugin development:

[A Plugin Development Pattern](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern) and 
[jQuery Plugin Design Patterns](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-plugin-design-patterns-part-i/)

Comment: Don't answer by linking to another question. Comment instead and vote to close if you can. *Edit: This was before the other links have been added.*

Comment: Ok Felix. Good to know. But also i added some other links. I will do as you say. Thanks for warning.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is based on the [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth). You "can" write your module in the same manner.  However, there are options.

You can write AMD-style using the [CommonJS specification](http://www.commonjs.org/).  Here is [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063267/what-does-the-define-protocol-outlined-in-commonjs-specification-buy-me) on it.